# django-rest-framework days-of-week representation in model

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, model

I want to create a schedule model to schedule media on days of the week

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()

    week_days = ???
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

but the problem is with week_days it can have multiple days how do I design the week_days field in the Django rest framework?

Answer (score 1):

Create a model for days of week, and use a M2M field in Schedule model

models.py

```
class DaysOfWeek(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=10)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
    

class Schedule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=50)
    week_days = models.ManyToManyField(DaysOfWeek, related_name="schedules", verbose_name="Days of Week")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serilaizers.py

```
class ScheduleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    week_days = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=DaysOfWeek.objects.all(), many=True,)

    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = ['name', 'week_days']
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets


class ScheduleView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ScheduleSerializer
    queryset = Schedule.objects.all()
    pagination_class = None
```

urls.py

As we are using the `ModelViewSet` in views.py, we can use the router to set the URL and use a single URL with all the http methods (get, put, patch, delete etc)

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'schedule', ScheduleView, basename='schedule')
```

In postman, use  `/schedule/` to create and get list.

To get object, update or delete, use `/schedule/<id>/`

Comment: can I know how the serializer and view work for this model?

Comment: Sure. I have updated the answer with the view and serializer.